# Cannot delete first node from the linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Below is my complete code of a Node class to create nodes in a linked list along with some methods to add more nodes to the list, print out all list contents and delete a node from the list:

```
public class Node {
Object data;
Node next;

public Node(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void printList() {
    Node node = this;
    while (node != null) {
        System.out.println(node.data);
        node = node.next;
    }
}

public void add(Object data) {

    Node node = this;
    while (node.next != null) {
        node = node.next;
    }
    node.next = new Node(data);
}

public void delete(Object data) {
    Node node = this;

    if (node.data.equals(data)) {
        node = node.next;
        return;
    }

    while (node.next != null) {
        if (node.next.data.equals(data)) {
            node.next = node.next.next;
            return;
        }
        node = node.next;
    }
}
```

}

All methods work fine, except the delete method won't remove the node if it's the first node. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How you keeping the first node, add complete code here.

Comment: I would also use reference to the previous element then it would be simpler to do what you want.

Comment: You need to tell us where you save your first node. Your `if (node.data.equals(data))` only works if you replace your former first node with firstNode.next

Comment: in other words: `node = node.next` is not doing much since `node` is not being used after that assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove the first `Node` with your current implementation, because first node is `this`, and you can't change it inside the `Node` class. What you can do though, is to change your delete method a little bit and return a new instance of your `Node` class.

```
public Node delete(Object data) {
    Node node = this;
    if (node.data.equals(data)) {
        return node.next;
    }
    while (node.next != null) {
        if (node.next.data.equals(data)) {
            node.next = node.next.next;
            return node;
        }
        node = node.next;
    }
    return null;
}
```

So if you want to remove the first node, you'll have to put it in a new variable, or reassing it. Example:

```
 Node node = new Node(1);
 node.add(2);
 node.add(4);
 node.add(3);
 node.delete(3);
 node = node.delete(1);
 node.printList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, that you never remove a node. All you do in your `delete(Object data)` method is to change your local variable `Node node`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you invoking the printList on the first node. Its not right way to do. You can define LinkedList class and inside that you can have private static nested Node class.

```
class LinkedList{
 private Node head; 
 private static class Node{
   //define the methods here
  }

}
```

For current solution, you can change the delete method and return the reference of node.

```
public Node delete(Object data) {
    Node node = this;

    if (node.data.equals(data)) {
        node = node.next;
        return node;
    }

    while (node.next != null) {
        if (node.next.data.equals(data)) {
            node.next = node.next.next;
        }
        node = node.next;
    }
    return node;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node node = new Node(10);
    node.add(20);
    node.add(30);

    node = node.delete(10);
    System.out.println("After Deletion of 10");

    node.printList();

    node = node.delete(20);
    System.out.println("After Deletion of 20");

    node.printList();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete a node from linked list, we need to do following steps.
1) Find previous node of the node to be deleted.
2) Changed next of previous node.
3) Free memory for the node to be deleted.

```
void deleteNode(int key)
{
    // Store head node
    Node temp = head, prev = null;

    // If head node itself holds the key to be deleted
    if (temp != null && temp.data == key)
    {
        head = temp.next; // Changed head
        return;
    }

    // Search for the key to be deleted, keep track of the
    // previous node as we need to change temp.next
    while (temp != null && temp.data != key)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp.next;
    }    

    // If key was not present in linked list
    if (temp == null) return;

    // Unlink the node from linked list
    prev.next = temp.next;
}
```

source:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-3-deleting-node/